# Enable checkbox B only when checkbox A is enabled and the other way around

Tags: javascript, jsp, dom, jsp-tags

I have a two columns of checkboxes with predictable names. How can I disable a checkbox in column B when the ones in column a is unchecked and only enable it when the first the checkbox a is enabled?

```
 <dmf:checkbox 
 name="someNameAColumnNumber"
 value="true" 
 onclick = "enableColumnBCheckBox" runatclient="true" 
 />
```

Is there something like on checkvalue = true  set equivalent checkbox B to true and the other way around?

**EDIT** the checkboxes are not in a form.. they are in a nested table.
**EDIT2** should work only in IE6 (I know....) not looking for cross browser compatibility

Comment: This sounds like a UI that would benefit from having sets of radio buttons (A/B/None) rather than having checkboxes that don't quite work like normal checkboxes (and need JS to implement sane state checking).

Comment: @David Dorward: No, that's not the point at all. I think there's a rather straightforward application for this, if B is a sub-option to A. Otherwise, Ayrad would probably have wanted the disabling to work both ways, which was not requested at all. Rather, imagine a checkbox that says "You may send me e-mails", which enables the checkboxes "once a month", "when i receive a private message", "etc"

Comment: Yes David Hedlund, the second checkbox doesn't make sense to be checked unless the the first one is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way that works as onclick event.

```
function toggleCheckBoxB(source) {

           var cbAID= source.id;

            var cbBID;
            cbBID= cbAID.replace("A", "B");


            if ( source.checked == 1 ) 
            {
                document.getElementById(cbBID).disabled = false;
            }
            else 
            {
                document.getElementById(cbBID).disabled = true;
                document.getElementById(cbBID).checked = 0;
            }

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

are you using any javascript framework currently? if not, i recommend jQuery. this could be done in pure javascript, and it'd be pretty easy to get almost-crossbrowser-support, but for real crossbrowser support, i definitely recommend using an existing framework. assuming jQuery:

```
$('#checkboxA').click(function() {
    $('#checkboxB')[0].disabled = !this.checked;
});
```

Comment: or `$('#checkboxB').attr('disabled', !this.checked);`